# Change the bordercolor of the selecteditem from an array of objects

Tags: react-native

I want to change the bordercolor of the selecteditem from my array which i'll map it on a button
*array= [{id: 0, name: "josh" }, {id: 1, name: "tim"} , {id:2, name:"jonathan"}]*. how can I achieve this?? if I select 1 from the button all border color's changed. Please help me, i'm new with react native. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create two styles, one for simple item and another for selected item. And then you can apply based on condition. Here is the example :

```js
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { useState } from "react";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const yourArray = [
    { id: 0, name: "josh" },
    { id: 1, name: "tim" },
    { id: 2, name: "jonathan" },
  ];
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={yourArray}
      extraData={yourArray}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={[styles.listItem, selectedItem === item.id ? styles.selectedItem : null]}
          onPress={() => setSelectedItem(item.id)}
        >
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  listItem: {
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#dddddd'
  },
  selectedItem: {
    borderColor: '#00ff00',
  },
});

export default YourComponent;
```